# Как вывести "YES" или "NO" не используя операторы ветвления

Tags: c++, алгоритм

У меня есть задача в которой нужно вывести "YES" или "NO" , не используя операторы ветвления if , switch ....

Вот условие:

Напишите программу, которая определяет, попадает ли заданная точка в заштрихованную область. Граничные точки входят в область.

--------|-5//////1|-----------|7///////13|---------->

Формат входных данных

Вводится вещественное число x, которое по модулю не превосходит 105 и задано с точностью до двух знаков после запятой.

Формат выходных данных

Вывести «YES», если координаты точки попадают в данную область, и «NO» в противном случае.

Примеры

Входные данные |    10.00 |  YES

Выходные данные | 0.00  |  YES

Я додумался как выводить 1 или 0. Но вот "YES" или "NO" не знаю как.

P.S. Нельзя использовать массивы и функции

Comment: Вы уточните что можно использовать, а что нельзя. Дело в том, что строка это массив `char`. "использовать строки" и "не использовать массивы" это взаимоисключающие параграфы

Comment: @gil9red Eсли люди не знают ни условий , ни массивов , ни функций , то как им решать?

Comment: Это же базовые знания :) первые страницы любого учебника по программированию :)

Answer (score 3):

Вот вам вариант от @KoVadim из которого выброшено объявление массива:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void show(int i)
{
    cout << ("NO\0YES\0" + i*3);
}
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    show(0);
    cout << "\n";
    show(1);
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Но как я уже писал в комментарии к вопросу, **строка это массив `char`**. Невозможно использовать строки и не использовать массивы.

Answer (score 2):

Вот Вам маленький пример. Разберетесь?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void show(int i)
{
    const char a[] = "NO\0YES\0";
    cout << (a + i*3);
}
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    show(0);
    cout << "\n";
    show(1);
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое , конечно , но наш преподаватель не разрешает использовать методы и массивы , поскольку в группе знаю их только я.Вот в чём проблема

Comment: @MatvieiSkufin, а строки он использовать разрешает?  Тогда у меня для него есть новость...

Comment: Нет , мы их тоже не прошли

Comment: @MatvieiSkufin, как так не прошли? А `yes`/`no` вы как выводите, по буквам индусским кодом?

Comment: @PinkTux До этого во всех задачах нужно было выводить 0 или 1

Comment: Методы Вы точно использовать не сможете. В С++ нет методов. Без функций тоже в С/С++ код никак не написать.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char *answers[] = { "NO", "YES" };
bool rc = isPointInRegion(/* ... */);
std::cout << answers[ (size_t)rc ];
```

Comment: Нельзя использовать массивы :(

Comment: @MatvieiSkufin, тогда вариант KoVadim вам подойдёт (в предположении, что ваш преподаватель не догадывается о том, что строки - тоже массивы)

Comment: Я думаю он не настолько глуп .

Comment: @MatvieiSkufin, значит, это вы чего-то не понимаете. Покажите ваш код для вывода хоть каких-то данных, который не использует строки.

Comment: Я думал под строками , вы подразумеваете string.